# Why user's activities is always empty?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am requesting https://graph.facebook.com/me/activities having user_activities permission, but it always return empty data response:

```
{ "data": [] }
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that there are

- Activities listed in the user profile
- The permission is indeed set, check with `/me/permissions`
- You aren't setting it in your app settings, it needs to be set in code

Comment: I was misunderstanding about the /activities API.
I go to my profile page, I choose the 'Activities' tab of Likes section, click 'Like' suggested activities. Then I can get the data via /me/activities! Thanks!